# Can't remove forced HTTPS redirect from Nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, redirect, https

I had originally setup my Nginx configuration to automatically redirect HTTP to HTTPS. Due to my work security policy and Cloudflare integration, HTTPS will not resolve inside my network.

I'd simply like to remove the forced redirect to HTTPS. But after commenting out the block with the URI rewrite, the server still redirects automatically.

Here's my default config for Nginx

```
#HTTPS redirect (if necessary)
#server {
#       listen      80;
#       server_name example.com;
#       rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
#}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        listen 443 ssl spdy;
        root /var/www/example/current/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        spdy_chunk_size 8k;
        spdy_headers_comp 7;

        server_name example.com;
        # Point to ssl certificates
        ssl_certificate /root/example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /root/example.com.key;
        # Allow only secure TLS protocols
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        #ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;

        ssl on;

        # Set the buffer size to 1400 bytes (that way it fits into a single MTU$
        ssl_buffer_size 1400;
#       add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=63072000;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1280;
        gzip_buffers    16 8k;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_http_version 1.0;
        gzip_types    text/plain text/html text/css application/javascript appl$
        gzip_vary on;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm$
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_nam$
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|woff2?)$ {
                #gzip on;
                #gzip_vary on;
                expires 168h;
                add_header Pragma public;
                add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revali$
                add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
        }


        #include /etc/nginx/global/*;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, remove `ssl on;`

Second, you had `Strict-Transport-Security` header and browsers remembered that for 2 years (as that commented out header says). Add it back with `max-age=0` to remove the effect.

If you can't do that (or want immediate effect) clear HSTS from your browser like [this article](http://classically.me/blogs/how-clear-hsts-settings-major-browsers) says.